# Hard disk usage 100 % without any read or write activity

Tags: ubuntu, hard-disk, cp

I started a big file transfer and it's taken a long time. I checked the disk activity with `nmon` and it says the (NTFS) disk is being 100 % busy and read and write speeds are at zero.

I used `cp -r myFolder/ newLocation/` to copy the files.

Is it stuck? Can I do something about it without restarting the whole copying process?

Answer (score 0):

```
rsync -av myFolder newLocation
```

It will pick up where it left off.
Linux normally needs some tuning to work with NTFS smoothly.